# Oracle SQL Implicit Conversion Issue

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I'm experiencing an unexpected behaviour in Oracle 11g Express Database when using a comparison involving a string and a numeric value. According to the Oracle documentation, when comparing values of different data types, implicit conversion should occur.

Here's the SQL query that I'm running:

```sql
SELECT 'TRUE' FROM DUAL WHERE '3' > 20;
```

According to Oracle's guidelines, the string '3' should be implicitly converted to a numeric data type for the comparison. However, I observe that instead of converting '3' into numeric, it appears that the numeric value 20 is being converted into a string. As a result, the comparison seems to be based on string ordering rather than numeric ordering.

[Here is the image of SQL while running this query.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5MzM.png)

I have referred to the Oracle documentation, but I couldn't find a clear explanation for this behavior. Can someone help me understand why the implicit conversion is not occurring as expected in this specific case?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

I expected the implicit conversion to occur as described in the Oracle documentation, where the string '3' would be converted to a numeric value for the comparison. However, the observed behavior suggests that the numeric value 20 is being treated as a string.

Comment: looks like uncharted water of undocumented behaviour. tried to [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/aWoK8mcH) it, but your query doesnt have the same output with the screenshot.

Comment: The database is exactly correct, as `3` is not greater than `20`. As strings, `'3'` _is_ greater than `'20'`, but what you are seeing is 0 rows fetched and the 'TRUE' is actually a column header, not the data. Try it with `SELECT 'True' FROM dual WHERE '31' > 20;` - note capitalised `True` and `31` is greater than `20`.

Comment: What is the exact result?

Comment: @BagusTesa, Oracle database already contains a single-column & single-row table named DUAL owned by SYS. There's also a public synonym so that every user *sees* that table. We do **not** create it in our schema (although there's no problem in doing so, as you demonstrated), but ... I've never actually seen anyone doing it, not in Oracle. That only causes confusion. We do create TEST, TEMP, STUDENT, EXAMPLE or whichever name you want, but not DUAL.

Comment: @AsifShahzad, this demonstrates why mixing datatypes is a bad idea. The proper thing to do is to compare 3 and 20, not '3' and 20. If you can't avoid that for some reason, then explicitly convert the operand of your choice rather than letting Oracle choose: `where to_number('3') > 20`

Comment: @Littlefoot oh, nice to know. thank you.

Comment: Never rely on implicit behaviour *(even when there are codified rules for datatype order of precedence)*. In all languages Explicit is ***always*** better coding practice than implicit. I wouldn't accept this behaviour from any team member, for any language.

Answer (score 1):

Do not get yourself dependant on Oracle's implicite conversions for there is no way to know when it will be successfuly implemented and when not. Let's take your query as an example:

1. is char '3' bigger then num 20  /  also is num 20 lesser than char '3'

```sql
SELECT 'TRUE' FROM DUAL WHERE '3' > 20;
SELECT 'TRUE' FROM DUAL WHERE 20 < '3';
```

Both return no rows - like Oracle  implicitelly converted char '3' into number 3

2. is char '3' lesser than num 20   /  also is num 20 bigger than char '3'

```sql
SELECT 'TRUE' FROM DUAL WHERE '3' < 20;
SELECT 'TRUE' FROM DUAL WHERE 20 > '3';
```

Both return TRUE - so it looks like there was the same conversion implemented again

3. can we do the addition with char values

```sql
SELECT 'TRUE' FROM DUAL WHERE '20' + '3' = 23;
```

The answer is TRUE.

One could conclude that there is nothing wrong with implicite conversions but in my experience the "ORA-01722: invalid number" error will pop up sooner or later. Having char value means that there is a possibility to store something else - not just numbers and it will take you some time before you find out what is happening with sql that worked so good for long time.
So, compare and operate numbers with numbers OR chars with chars - do your own explicite conversion (handle the possibility of something else in char value) - use To_Char() or To_Number() as suggested by Paul W in comments.
Additionally, not all db versions/setups act the same.

Answer (score 0):

> However, I observe that instead of converting '3' into numeric,...

Plain wrong observation. If you slightly modifies you query, that the *numeric conversion* would fail, you'll see the failure

```
SELECT 'TRUE' FROM DUAL WHERE '3a' > 20;
ORA-01722: invalid number
```

The best way to see what is Oracle dooing is to use `explain plan`

I replace your string with a bind variable `:x` because otherwise Oracle recognise the false predicate and eliminates it completely.

```
EXPLAIN PLAN  SET STATEMENT_ID = 'jara1' into   plan_table  FOR
SELECT 'TRUE' FROM DUAL WHERE :x > 20;
 
SELECT * FROM table(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY('plan_table', 'jara1','ALL'));
```

The result is as follows, check the **numeric conversion** in `Predicate Information`

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation        | Name | Rows  | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT |      |     1 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  FILTER          |      |       |            |          |
|   2 |   FAST DUAL      |      |     1 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   1 - filter(TO_NUMBER(:X)>20)
```